# How to pass hash reference created in parameter at call time of a method?

Tags: perl

```
sub printName{ 
    $ref = shift;
    print "$ref->{name}";
};

printName(\%hs = (name => "vicky"));
```

This is giving the error, is there any way to pass?
Thank you

Comment: `printName({name => "vicky"});`

Answer (score 1):

Your subroutine is fine except you need to declare `$ref`. You can simply pass an anonymous hash to it like so:

`printName({ name => "vicky" });`